What Exchange Online APIs enable simple searches across all exchange messages for a tenant?
I would like to be able to get a count, or collection of message datetimes, for all messages sent to or received from a collection of external addresses.
It seems like the ComplianceSearch APIs can do this, but require Microsoft Purview to be purchased. Are there other APIs that can accomplish this task?

You can use a Message Trace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetrace?view=exchange-ps that will search the Message tracking logs which are have some time restrictions around. The old Office365 Reporting web services is still available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/o365-enterprise-developers/jj984325(v=office.15) (as Microsoft has yet to deliver any alternative to this) which can also be used to scan the Message Tracking logs.
